# Toggle to previous App on different Desktop on Mac

Tags: macos

On Mac I have Chrome app on Desktop 1 and Chrome app and Messages app on Desktop 2.

When I am on the Chrome app on Desktop 1 and I press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> I switch to Messages app.

How do I return to Chrome on Desktop 1?

When I am on Messages App on Desktop 1 and I press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> I open Chrome App on Desktop 2 and does not go back to Chrome App on Desktop 1 (which was the most recent prev active window)

Answer (score 0):

Spaces has never liked it if you have one app spread across more than one Space. It just confuses it.

I'd be tempted to use Spaces switching itself, rather than app switching. This will at least get you to the right Space, if not the right app.

By default, each Space you add is assigned a key command Ctrl/[Space number] but these are not activated automatically, you need to switch them on.

These are buried deep inside System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts… > Mission Control > Mission Control

[image]

[Fullscreen apps cannot be accessed this way, their Spaces don't have numbers. You have to move 'right a space' etc.]